# DotNetBrowser: System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, dotnetbrowser

When running one of the sample projects, I'm hitting the error below and there's no way for me to proceed. I'm using  DotNetBrowser 1.7.x, Visual Studio 2013 using runtime v4.5, and Windows 10. Can you please help me on this one?

> System.AccessViolationException' occurred in DotNetBrowser.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Cheers,
Jhessie

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the sample project on 32-bit or 64-bit platform? If this issue is reproducible only for 64-bit, there is some kind of a configuration issue in the project. We have noticed a very similar behavior a few times, and after playing around with configuration it is gone somehow.

The reason of this behavior is still unclear.

If you want to help DotNetBrowser team to find the exact cause of the issue, you can send them a sample solution for which this behavior is constantly reproducible.

**Upd.: The AccessViolationException issue is fixed in DotNetBrowser 1.8.1.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the temporary files and rebuild the project. Please make sure that you have selected either 'x86' or 'x64' configuration, not 'Any CPU'.

You can find the temporary files in the following location:

```
%Temp%\dotnetbrowser-chromium-*
```